# agm-info-window - How to change position to right

Tags: angular, google-maps

I am using angular google maps and   to display maps and marker and info window. Info window is placed always on top. How to change its position to right?

```
<agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" [zoom]="zoom">
  <agm-marker *ngFor="let m of mapArrayList; let i = index" (markerClick)="clickedMarker(infowindow)" [latitude]="m.geometry.location.lat"
    [longitude]="m.geometry.location.lng">
    <agm-info-window #infowindow>
<div>{{name}}</div>
  </agm-info-window>
```

Comment: I think this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38167162/google-map-infowindow-position-on-right-side)can help you enough :)

Comment: Please note that my question is related to angular not on javascript. I am using angular google-maps. Please dont post irrelevant answers. I have raised a bounty and I havent got a proper answer. At the end, I have now lost 50 reputations.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for this late reply... I don't have any experience with angular google maps, but it looks like you might be able to tweak the look and the behaviour of the window via the plugin **Snazzy Info Window**. https://github.com/atmist/snazzy-info-window

Cf. the **placement** property (top / bottom / left / right) of the info window:
https://github.com/atmist/snazzy-info-window#placement

In order to use Snazzy in combination with Angular Google Maps: https://angular-maps.com/guides/snazzy-info-window/custom-info-windows-with-snazzy-info-window/

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can check this link it describe how to change the position of info bar [Components AgmSnazzyInfoWindow](https://angular-maps.com/api-docs/agm-snazzy-info-window/components/AgmSnazzyInfoWindow.html)

pass the position into the `[placement]` like `top, bottom, right, left`